# force SSH (on client) to ask for password (Xubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, passwords, hibernate, ssh-agent

Please, how do I configure the SSH-asking-password politics? I am using hibernate a lot on my laptop. The problem is that when I resume and make a SSH connection which I had already done in the session (turning on the computer, hibernating, resuming = still the same session), it does not ask for password again.

Normally, when I use ssh from terminal for the first time, I have to enter my RSA certificate password to the popup window.

Using GNU/Linux Xubuntu 15.04
Thanks.

Comment: So you want to configure your ssh agent to not remember your password for your private key?

Answer (score 0):

You can add to some hibernate script call to `ssh-add -D`, which will remove all your identities from agent. But don't forget to add them after wake up.

Better way would be only locking up agent using `ssh-add -x` switch (automatically or manually) before going to hibernate.

Or you can just limit time for what the passphrase will be stored using `-t` switch for `ssh-agent` or `ssh-add`.

Comment: I like the timeout option - where to set it? I mean, I do not run the agent manually, so it has to have some config file somewhere...
Locking it with extra password is interresting, but I would prefer other way.

Comment: it should be possible to use `ssh-add -t 10m` which would give your password 10 minutes life before the pass-phrase is forgotten. You can set it up in your `~/.bash_profile` so it will be executed as you log in.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, adding "ssh-add -t 10m" to ~/.bashrc does not work. After 10 minutes (even more), I am still able to ssh to the server without the popup prompt :/ Any other hint?

Comment: I forget to mention that you need to re-login or source that file to existing shell `. ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: I did relogin, of course :) Actually, to be sure, I've made a complete restart

Comment: hmm. This should work if you are using bash as your primary shell. Alternatively you can try to modify `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc-common` (on Fedora, Ubuntu will have similar file -- this is where is the agent started) by adding command-line arguments to ssh-agent.

Comment: Yes, I do have bash set. If I figure it out once and if I remember, I will post a solutin here. So far unknown. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried this but [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/20996) suggests:

Unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable, then `ssh` will ask for the private key password itself.

Comment: this is not what you want to do, because it will leave your agent running, only you will lose the connection for it. Better way is to call `ssh-agent -k`, which will kill the agent.

Comment: it is not possible:
<code>$ ssh-agent -k
SSH_AGENT_PID not set, cannot kill agent</code>